# Should we cleanup and burninate the [meta] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

### Problem

As of now, the tag [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) (supposed to be used for the HTML-element) is misused for question regarding

- [Facebook/](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) different products by Facebook (aka. Meta. Given the relative recency of Facebook's rebranding, this issue is with newer questions.)
- The package named "meta" in [the programming language R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta+r)

### Proposed solution

<s>Make [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) a synonym for [meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags)</s>

As per suggestion in the comments, [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) should be burninated ([again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)) and then blocked from being created.

Comment: There are 1.6k questions tagged meta. And 1.1k of them [don't include HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta+-html). Is [meta] really just about [meta-tags]?

Comment: I, personally, don't see how Meta (the company) is on-topic. There's a reason we don't have a [[tag:Microsoft]] tag, for example. The use of [[tag:meta]] with [[tag:facebook]] seems to be tagging for the sake of tagging the company name, where as [[tag:facebook]] is meant for when developing apps for Facebook.

Comment: According to it's description (*"Meta elements are the HTML or XHTML <meta … > element used to provide structured metadata about a Web page"*), @VLAZ, it's *supposed* to be, however, it's clearly not being used that way (as users don't know how to read). Rather than a synonym, it seems that disambiguation is needed, if r is involved in many of the questions.

Comment: @VLAZ in theory yes. But as you pointed out not in practice. As is, the tag is pretty much useless. That why it should be made a synonym.

Comment: @A-Tech making it a synonym doesn't solve the problem as it stands though; if [[tag:meta]] should be a synonym of [[tag:meta-tags]] then first any questions with the **wrong** tags need to be addressed. If there are ~1,100 questions incorrectly tagged with [[tag:meta]] making it a synonym would make about 30% of the questions tagged with [[tag:meta-tags]] have the wrong tag, as many should be tagged with a tag appropriate for r's meta package (if one is needed) or have the tag removed as it's referencing a company not a technology.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to burn/disambiguate than to rename

Comment: Based on personal experience, making it a synonym won't really solve the issue of mistagging because most new users do *not* read/care about the tag excerpt.

Comment: "*That why it should be made a synonym.*" no? It means that you'll move all the Facebook-related questions (and other non-HTML) to be with in the same place as the HTML questions. Which you'd recognise is the situation right now. Synonym means that the two tags are *exactly* the same with *exactly* the same usage and any question already tagged [meta] should have been tagged [meta-tag] instead. And according to your own question that's not the case. Hence synonym doesn't make any sense here. It should be disambiguated at the very least at first. Probably burninated.

Comment: Oh, gets better... seems that tag was already removed. [See revision #2 from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10387734/revisions) (points to [this MSE question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) but I get a 404 for it). Then in 2013 (revision #4) it was made to be about meta tags. I suspect the tag wiki update wasn't correct according to the usage at that point. So, it seems like nobody really cleared what the tag was about. A tag wiki was added but [didn't match usages from before it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240567)

Comment: I'm happy to participate in tag cleanup first, so we can get down to a clean set of questions that are about `<meta>` tags, and then synonymize it, if that's what people are for. We have [tag:meta-tags], [tag:metadata], and [tag:metaprogramming]. Are there other on-topic uses of the term "meta" that need to be declared?

Comment: @TylerH [Something called "Clojure meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4673011). Sounds convincingly like an actual term but I've no familiarity with Clojure. Also [tag:meta-boxes] - something to do with Wordpress.

Comment: @TylerH maybe something along the lines of a new `r-package-meta` -tag?

Comment: @VLAZ That is covered by [tag:metadata]; it refers to preserving or attaching metadata to objects.

Comment: @A-Tech I think an [tag:r-meta] or [tag:r-meta-package] tag would be good.

Comment: @VLAZ lets take [tag:r-meta-package] as it leaves no room for misinterpretation.

Comment: Found another usage: there is apparently something called "meta object" in QT. Uh, there seem to also be two tags for it: [[tag:qmetaobject]] and [[tag:metaobject]]. Those might need merger (didn't look too hard at them). Thankfully there aren't many questions, either.

Comment: (There is a conflict in the references.)

Comment: Also, I've seen several questions tagged [[tag:meta]] presumably because they are about a "wider subject" in general. Example of one (just the latest I found): [Why would I use an SSIS package in SQL Server 2008 as opposed to some other technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6283689) The only hit for "meta" on the page is the tag. Few others I saw seem similar in that they don't talk about *a thing* called meta. Just a "meta question", is my best guess for the usage. For those the tag should just be dropped.

Comment: @VLAZ Added a tag to the answer below for QT; [tag:metaobject] seems more general and not necessarily the same thing (though there may be some overlap)

Answer (score 10):

Since it has been removed and 'do-not-used' once before back in 2012 or 2013, a suggestion on what to do with [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) this time around is as follows:

1. Cleanup the tag. Existing tags that questions can be retagged as:

   - [meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) for HTML `<meta>` tags
   - [metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metadata) for questions about meta data usage (including Clojure's Meta command
   - [metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metaprogramming) for questions about meta programming
   - [meta-boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-boxes) for questions about the WordPress feature
   - [qmetaobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qmetaobject) for questions about the QT objects
   - [r-meta-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-meta-package) may need to be created for the R package
   - [custom-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-fields) for metadata added to WordPress posts
   - [windows-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-key) or [modifier-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier-key) for handling "meta keys" like <kbd>Win</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc.

   Questions about classes named Meta (like Django) can have the tag removed.

   Off-topic questions can be closed to be deleted.
2. Remove and blacklist the tag.

Comment: Hmm, what about [Open Graph meta tags](https://ogp.me/)? They *are* meta tags but very specialised. Is a new tag needed? In either case, I see a lot of questions about Open Graph tagged [facebook] which should be [[tag:facebook-opengraph]] instead.

Comment: Also is it really the best decision to drop the [meta] tag on questions that concern the `class Meta` concept in Django? Maybe [[tag:metadata]] fits but it does seem to be a distinct concept and I've seen a few questions that are *directly* about Django and Meta.

Comment: @VLAZ We don't have tags for classes in other languages do we? I know C# doesn't have them for namespaces for example. EDIT: OK, maybe [it does, unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.net). Just the language tag and maybe a tag covering the concept relevant to OP's problem/question should be enough, I think.

Comment: Bonus points for setting up relevant tag combinations for automation; if we can get CMs to handle the bulk of the renames via database magic, we'd save a lot of manual work. The more we don't have to retag manually, the better

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Do you have an example of what you mean? Something like "this question with [tag:meta] is also tagged with [tag:php] therefore retag [tag:meta] on it to [tag:php-meta], no matter what"?

Comment: It doesn't have to be on a per-question level (there's thousands of them after all), but this mainly applies to obvious targets. For instance, we can trivially assume [html][meta] refers to [meta-tags], so this would be a candidate for automation. If there's any other similar claims that can be made, those would apply. If there's some that _mostly_ apply, we can fix the outliers manually and apply the claim to the rest. For instance if [python][django] overwhelmingly refers to Django's meta class, whatever that works there would be applicable, and the outliers can be manually handled

Comment: Other stuff also applies; automatically removing the tag from everything else is also fine (and probably useful; synonyms can be sorted out separately if needed)

Comment: Or simply, a list of [meta][sometag] with some action applied, such as replacing [meta] with a more applicable tag, if that tag also makes sense to have. Vaving "remove the tag from everything else" probably makes sense here as well, seeing as the goal is to get rid of the tag, but it really depends on how much needs to be manually handled. If there's a lot, it might be easier to auto-retag and blacklist first, and review the rest later, but it really doesn't matter as long as there's a way to keep track of progression.

Answer (score 6):

The tag doesn't really meet the burnination criteria, since (according to the tag usage guidance at least) it unambiguously refers to a very specific, on-topic concept (the HTML `meta` tags). I do think that the tag is poorly named, though, which appears to be leading to a lot of confusion on how to use it. The fact that the tag usage guidance is quite clear about how it's supposed to be used doesn't really help much because most people don't read tag usage guidance.

Given that there's already a [meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) tag that's in widespread use (over 2,300 questions of today), this tag appears to be 100% redundant anyway. That being said, I'd definitely support a retag effort and just blacklisting the tag.